# Box2D Light to ignore all bodies

Tags: box2d, libgdx

I have type of light in my game that needs to penetrate all obstacles, how can I achieve this?

I tried this:

```
final short IGNORED = 0x001;

FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
fd.filter.categoryBits = IGNORED;
fd.filter.groupIndex = IGNORED;
fd.filter.maskBits = IGNORED;

new PointLight(rayHandler, 1000, Color.CYAN, 1000, 200, 400);

PointLight.setContactFilter(IGNORED,IGNORED,IGNORED);
```

but I still get shadows from that light.

Another thing is that my shadows are black and continue forever, is there a way to create shadows that arent so dark and long?

Basically this is what I get:
[image]

but this is what I want:
[image]

Comment: Sounds more like a graphics question than a box2d or a physics question

Answer (score 3):

If you only want everything to become brighter you might want to try using ambient light. For instance:

```
rayHandler.setAmbientLight(0.5f);
```

makes everything 50% brighter, which may achieve the effect you want. You can also add colors to this (to for instance achieve a sunset-ish vibe).

Comment: This is a much better answer than the first.

Answer (score 1):

To "ignore all bodies" you can just use xRay parameter and you don't need filters, but in your topic i see another question. Anyway:

```
PointLight pointLight = new PointLight(...);
pointLight.setXray(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with libgdx in particular, but box2d allows you to create a body as a sensor.

From the manual:

> Sometimes game logic needs to know when two fixtures overlap yet there
>   should be no collision response. This is done by using sensors. A
>   sensor is a fixture that detects collision but does not produce a
>   response.
>
> You can flag any fixture as being a sensor. Sensors may be static or
>   dynamic. Remember that you may have multiple fixtures per body and you
>   can have any mix of sensors and solid fixtures.
>
> Sensors do not generate contact points. There are two ways to get the
>   state of a sensor:
>
> b2Contact::IsTouching b2ContactListener::BeginContact and EndContact

So you should be able to use your contact listener to detect if it is colliding, but not get a collision response out of the physics system.

Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that `to penetrate all obstacles` in your game then `make them sensor true.`
If you want to check collision then you have to `check collision in the BeginContact or end contact.`

Just like

```
fd.isSensor = true;
```